# Modern TeXes handling of Unicode

Tags: xetex, pdf, luatex, unicode

I just may be misinformed, but roughly:

1. Is still true that PDF is in principle able to use only 8bit encoding vectors?
2. If not, how do LuaTeX/XeTeX handle larger glyph sets?

Comment: This question commits the fallacy sometimes known as 'complex question'. It cannot be answered because the condition any answer must assume true necessarily undermines the cogency of any response to the question asked. Yet to reject that condition is to fail to answer the question.

Comment: What makes you think PDF can only use 8 bit fonts? (And, actually, it is really the encodings we are talking about. I think that PDF doesn't deal with the 8 bit fonts you are probably referring to ever.)

Comment: AFAICR, PDf is based on PS, and PostScript could handle only 8 bit encoding vectors. (Better?)

Comment: @TarsTarkas: And why do you believe that PDF was not improved in that aspect compared to PostScript?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I was confused because I still use the old dvi>ps>pdf chain, and just occurred to me that modern TeXes handle unicode fonts and not only old-style 8bit pfbs. As I said, I was misinformed; or rather, outdated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply a copy of an answer posted on Stack Overflow. [plinth writes the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163065/3186474):

> In the PDF reference in chapter 3, this is what they say about
>   Unicode:
>
> > Text strings are encoded in either PDFDocEncoding or Unicode character encoding. PDFDocEncoding is a superset of the ISO Latin 1
> >     encoding and is documented in Appendix D. Unicode is described in the
> >     Unicode Standard by the Unicode Consortium (see the Bibliography). For
> >     text strings encoded in Unicode, the first two bytes must be 254
> >     followed by
> >     255. These two bytes represent the Unicode byte order marker, U+FEFF, indicating that the string is encoded in the UTF-16BE (big-endian)
> >     encoding scheme specified in the Unicode standard. (This mechanism
> >     precludes beginning a string using PDFDocEncoding with the two
> >     characters thorn ydieresis, which is unlikely to be a meaningful
> >     beginning of a word or phrase).

Hence the answer to question 1 is that it is not now true, even if it was true at one time. It follows that question 2 is beside the point ('moot' for readers in North America).

Comment: Just another clarification: that means that while LuaTeX and XeTeX accept UTF8 as input encoding, the final PDFs are UTF16BE encoded. Correct?

Comment: Why would you delete the question? To stop other people finding it as well?

Comment: Yes, I think so. At least, that would be my understanding.